# Get data on relation 'B' where relation 'A' does not exits in same id in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have two tables named "Student" and "Subscription". If there is at least one active plan in the subscription database, I check by date. I need to get the data if no plan is active. Below is the code I used to get the data. But this is wrong because in this query I am getting all the expired data and I should get the data only if there is not even one plan active in the student id.

```
$expired_student = Student::wherehas('getSubscription', function ($query) use ($current_date){
        $query->where('expired_at','<',$current_date);
    })->where('status',1)->count();
```

anyone can please help me to solve this problem

Comment: I assume the "status" is the flag pointing were the plan is active. So you should replace the "orWhere" with "where"

Comment: Actually is not clear what you want. What is that "getPayment"? Are those the subscriptions? And what are those two "status"? Do you have an status for the student and another for the subscriptions?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the query in the question. Here I have 2 tables Subscription table has multiple entries with same student_id I want number of students who don't have any active plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you Student model, you can define a relationship method called activeSubscriptions, like this:

```
public function activeSubscriptions() {
   return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class)->where(function($query) {
             $query->whereNull('expired_at')->orWhere('expired_at', '>', now());
          });
}
```

And you can use this function like this:

```
$expiredStudents = Student::doesntHave('activeSubscriptions')->get();
```